# Ionic recibir notificaciones con app apagada

Tags: ionic, push, notificaciones

Buen dia, un poco de ayuda, alguien ha recibido notificaciones push enviadas desde un servidor NodeJS usando socketio??  veo muchas respuestas con firebase, pero en mi caso, tengo montado un server con node y funciona muy bien, solo que al apagar la app o bloquear el teclefono, a los pocos segundos dejo de recibirlas y se desconecta del servidor, al encender y entrar a la app vuelvo a recibirlas pero se pierde el proposito de las notificaciones push.

Agradeceria su ayuda...